# use of accumulator in xslt 3.0 not working as I need

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have an XML in which I have a list of books with properties like title, price, author, additional price, artist, country etc.  XML is as below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <additionalprice>12.90</additionalprice>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <additionalprice>10.90</additionalprice>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
```

and so on

I want to write an XSLT 3.0 applied on XML to get an HTML. I want to use an accumulator to get a total number of books in the catalog. Although there are better methods, I just wanted to use accumulator for practicing purposes and print the total at the end of the table containing books where columns are title, author and total price. For filling title and author, I used for-each. Total price=price+ additionalPrice. I want to use iterate for filing the total price. Can anybody please help me with this. My incomplete stylesheet looks like the below:

```xml
<?xml version="3.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="2">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
       <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
       <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
       <th style="text-align:left">Total Price</th>
    </tr>
 <xsl:accumulator name="total" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="no">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="title" select="$value+1"/>
 </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
     <tr>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
       <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
     </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
         <tr bgcolor="#FFA500">
           <td> Total number of Books </td>
           <td> <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('total')"/</td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't want to use streaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#accumulator-declaration then you see that `xsl:accumulator` is a declaration, meaning you have to use it as a top-level element/child of the `xsl:stylesheet`, not inside of a template.

And an accumulator value is associated with a node and the functions like https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#func-accumulator-before "Returns the pre-descent value of the selected accumulator at the context node" so in your case, where you have a single template with the context node `/` is does not make much sense to access the accumulator before value, you rather need the `accumulator-after` value.

Finally you have to declare that the accumulator is to be applied to the default mode

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode use-accumulators="#all"/>

    <xsl:accumulator name="total" as="xs:integer" initial-value="0" streamable="no">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule match="title" select="$value + 1"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
                <table border="2">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Total Price</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFA500">
                        <td> Total number of Books </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('total')"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The above one does not work for me @Martin . Not sure why . On removing <td><xsl:value-of select="accumulator-after('total')"/></td> line, i get an output where the value that needs to be filled by accumulator is empty. I use https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp so I dont get the compile errors.

Comment: To use XSLT 3 you need to use an XSLT 3 processor, the tool you have linked to is not one. The XSLT 3 implementations known to me to be in line with the final XSLT 3 spec of this year are Saxon 9.8 and Altova 2017 R3 or 2018, so I suggest you try one of them if you want to use XSLT 3. Saxon 9.8 HE with your input fixed to be well-formed and complete and my snippet inside a complete `xsl:stylesheet` outputs `2` for the `accumulator-after('total')`, as does Altova XMLSpy 2018.

Comment: I have edited the code snippet and turned it into a complete stylesheet, just in case your troubles resulted from the previous snippet only having the relevant code for the body of the stylesheet.

Comment: After I started using xml spy from Altova, it works fine